# php cannot call python

Tags: python, php

When I call a simple python-script that blinks LED once, from a PHP-script via browser, nothing happens.

and I add these lines in the  sudoers file.

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
apache2 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
adm ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

`/var/www/html` `owner`&`Group` is `www-data`
and python script `owner`&`Group` is `www-data` also

what is the problem?

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['RedON']))
{
exec('sudo python /var/www/html/xbee.py');
}
if (isset($_POST['RedOFF']))
{
exec('sudo python /home/pi/xbee2.py');
}
if (isset($_POST['YellowON']))
{
exec('sudo python /var/www/html/xbee2.py');
}
if (isset($_POST['YellowOFF']))
{
exec('sudo python /var/www/gpio/yellow_off.py');
}
if (isset($_POST['GreenON']))
{
exec('sudo python /var/www/gpio/green_on.py');
}
if (isset($_POST['GreenOFF']))
{
exec('sudo python /var/www/gpio/green_off.py');
}
?>

  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
  <table
 style="width: 75%; text-align: left; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"
 border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">Turn LED on</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">Turn LED off</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="RedON">Red On</button></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="RedOFF">Red Off</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="YellowON">Yellow On</button></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="YellowOFF">Yellow Off</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="GreenON">Green On</button></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><button name="GreenOFF">Green Off</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Not: python script works in SSH Normally.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're problem is right off the bat, but there's a trick that might help us debug this a little easier. Wrap your exec statements like this: `echo(exec('sudo python /var/www/html/xbee.py 2>&1'));`.

Comment: I added two things there. First, `echo` the output of your exec statements. That will print anything that your python call returns to the webpage. That only gets you part of the way there though because whatever errors occur are printed to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. By adding `2>&1` following your python script, that will redirect the output that's meant for `stderr` to `stdout` so that `echo` can print it. Give that a try and let me know what errors show up.

Comment: You're also probably aware, but this is not a good practice to do on public facing pages :) It's a bit revealing about your system.

Comment: I triad before the same PHP and python script in the same Raspberry pi, and it is worked, because there was an error in Raspberry OS, I was format it, and when I trying to install the same script again don't work.

Comment: thank you hobenkr for your command I will try it and I will inform you.

Comment: I triad 
echo(exec('sudo python /var/www/html/xbee.py 2>&1')); and there is nothing happened, check this picture please,
https://www.dropbox.com/s/fskd7ghgtg36yvt/Capture.JPG?dl=0

Comment: Looks like don't have php installed or enabled - `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5`.  PHP 7 is probably available too if you want it.

Comment: Actually, it could be as simple as the fact you've called your file `index.html` not `index.php` so it's not running through the interpreter.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much @calcinai. it should be `index.php` not `index.html`

Comment: Good catch @calcinai! I would have never thought to ask that haha.

Comment: @calcinai, please post that as an answer, and Aymen, please accept it. Doing so will help others who visit this question in future.

Comment: I SEARCHED A LOT ..AT THE END ONLY SOLUTION THIS WORKED...JUST DO THIS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811253/execute-python-script-from-php

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem a lot of people face, and it's not always just due to a lack of sudo permission.

A couple of possible causes could be:

- Permission/`sudo` (as you are already aware)
- `python` might not be available in the `www-data` user's environment

Since you've been quite aggressive with your sudo permissions, it's probably not that.  There are two main ways (that I can think of) to resolve the second possibility.

- Use the complete path to `python` (e.g. `/usr/bin/python`) in your PHP script.  You can make sure you're using the same one as when you SSH by typing `which python`
- Make your scripts directly executable.  This would require 3 steps:

  1. Specify the interpreter (Python) with a shebang at the start of your python scripts.  A common way to do this is `#!/usr/bin/env python`
  2. Add the execute permission `chmod +x /var/www/gpio/x.py`
  3. Change your PHP code to reflect this `exec('sudo /var/www/gpio/x.py');`

*Alternatively*

I've been working on [a php library](https://github.com/calcinai/phpi) to overcome this exact issue.  It's native PHP and provides an asynchronous api for GPIO manipulation.  It doesn't require `sudo` for basic operations provided you add the `www-data` user to the `gpio` group.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to run Python scripts through PHP in a browser.

I believe the problem relies on the code in these Python files.
Probabily in your python code you import libraries that access some devices that need permission.

So you need to set the permission to the device itself, not to Phyton or the Python script.

For example, if your Python code reads data from the USB, you need to set the right permission to the right ttyUSB file in the device folder: `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [phpy - library for php](https://github.com/Raeen123/phpy).

PHP file:

```
<?php
  require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

  use app\core\App;

  $app = new App();
  $python = $app->python;
  $output = $python->gen(your python path,data....);
  $python->dump($output);
```

Python file:

```
import include.library.phpy as phpy
print(phpy.get_data(number of data , first = 1 , two =2 ...))
```

You can see also example in github page.